# Curl call yahoo weather new api OAuth

Tags: api, curl, yahoo-api

I am trying to do a curl call to the new yahoo weather API

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html

I got my API Keys and my app has been approved or whitelisted.

However I can't seem to get my curl call to work with OAuth authentication. I first tried with Postman to make the call, I was authorized but the results were empty. According to support " Using oauth1 in postman can get intermittent error."

So am I trying to do a curl call like so:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=sunnyvale,ca' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="(MY CLIENT ID)",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1547215497",oauth_nonce="kIDevCJSTBi",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="(MY GENERATED OAUTH SIGNATURE)"' --header 'Yahoo-App-Id: "(MY APP ID)"'
```

But I get this returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xml:lang="en-US" yahoo:uri="http://yahoo.com"><yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=&quot;OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR&quot;, realm=&quot;yahooapis.com&quot;</yahoo:description><yahoo:detail>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=&quot;OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR&quot;, realm=&quot;yahooapis.com&quot;</yahoo:detail></yahoo:error>
```

This is from the Yahoo Weather Developer page:

> GET /forecastrss?location=sunnyvale,ca HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com Yahoo-App-Id: YOUR_APP_ID
>   Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="YOUR_TIMESTAMP",oauth_nonce="YOUR_NONCE",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="YOUR_GENERATED_SIGNATURE" cache-control: no-cache

What Am I doing wrong? This is so frustrating.

Comment: Hm, nothing really stands out.  It does say you're signature is invalid.  You're **positive** you don't have any typos in your auth header?  You might also double-check that your account has the necessary access to that particular endpoint.

Comment: The signature was generated via postman, what is the proper way to generate a oauth signature.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I am trying too, their documentation is kinda useless, names parameters I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of curl request :

```
curl 'https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=sunnyvale,ca&format=json&oauth_consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=YOUR_TIMESTAMP&oauth_nonce=YOUR_NONCE&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=YOUR_GENERATED_SIGNATURE'
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

• `YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY` : Your consumer key
• `YOUR_TIMESTAMP` : Unix timestamp
• `YOUR_NONCE` : nounce
• `YOUR_GENERATED_SIGNATURE` : The encrypted signature.

Here are the steps using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (as you mentioned using it in the description) to generate a GET request to the [Yahoo Weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

**1) [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) configuration :**
[image: Postman configuration]

**2) Generate the curl command**
Then, in order to make the curl request you can press the code button and see the generated command.
[image: Generated curl command]

There are some Code examples in Java, PHP and NodeJS [on this page](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#rest-api).

Comment: So you paste screenshots instead of text?

Comment: @LtWorf : I updated the reply with an example of curl request.